# Cant find Exim 4 'helo_verify_hosts' configuration setting

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, exim

I'm trying to recreate the Exim GHOST vulnerability over my local network and have installed Debian 7 with Exim version 4.8. However I can't seem to find where the helo_try_verify_hosts or helo_verify_hosts options are. I thought it'd be in the exim4.conf.template or update-exim4.conf.conf file.

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean Exim `4.80`? You can add it to `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template`'s main section or a file in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main` if you are using a split config.

Comment: Yeah I only realised recently. I didn’t know you can just add the option yourself. Was looking everywhere to try find it haha. Thanks